# How could I get elements by a class name OR another class name?

Tags: javascript, class, getelementsbyclassname

I need to get elements by class name in order of appearance on the page. Here is an example of what I want to do :

```
<div class="class1">1</div>
<div class="class1">2</div>
<div class="class2">3</div>
<div class="class1">4</div>

var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('class1'||'class2');
```

Then my arr will have these values.

```
arr[0].innerHTML -> 1
arr[1].innerHTML -> 2
arr[2].innerHTML -> 3
arr[3].innerHTML -> 4
```

Is there any JavaScript function to do this ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [comma](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping) and [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class1, .class2');
```

Comment: @Quentin: I was about to do the same (you beat me by couple of seconds actually). Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class*="class"]')
```

With this selector you can get all the elements that have a class containing the word "class", so you don't have to list them comma separated.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.